# Bulldog skin problem

Tags: dogs, skin-condition, allergies

Friends, it is kind of complicated to describe the exact problem as a person that his main language is not English, but I'm trying my best.

I have got an 8 years old male bulldog, recently I realized some bumps in his back, first of all, I thought that could be a `Tick`, but I did not find anything.

[image]
[image]

It is like, on each bump, at end of hairs is stuck together like a scab, I asked his vet about them. Unfortunately, he was not sure about the main problem and he guessed this problem may be related to the liver.

[image]
[image]

My dog used to eat boiled chicken (sometimes with the skeleton), but during the last 60 days, I've changed his diet to dry food.

Has anyone faced such this problem before?

Comment: Have you tried a flea comb to check for parasites?  I can't be sure, but mites or fleas can cause scabby skin.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like caked on mud to me. Dogs run and play, sometimes kicking up dirt along the way. A fleck here and there can go unnoticed until you are petting them later. Once it's dried it would act just like a scab, as the hair grows it would also pull the dried mud off the skin with hairs trapped in the mess. Give the pup a good scrubdown, blow dry, spa day. And make notes if the problem repeats.

p.s. Your dog can consume and process raw chicken bones without an issue (because the bones are soft and digestible). But you should always avoid any kind of cooked bones. They often break and sharp pieces chip off, leading to serious intestinal issues.